# Why does the memccpy function use an int parameter?

Tags: c

`memccpy` is defined as:

```
void *memccpy(void *dest, const void *src, int c, size_t n)
```

I understand that integer `c` is used as an `unsigned char` by type casting.

Then I think

```
void *memccpy(void *dest, const void *src, unsigned char c, size_t n)
```

looks better. Is there any reason `memccpy` must use an `int` parameter?

Comment: I can't think of *any* standard library function that *doesn't* use `int` for a character argument, or function return value.

Comment: Also, it does allow c to be `-1` (EOF), resulting in `memcpy()` behavior.

Comment: @wildplasser My understanding of the [docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memccpy.html) is that `dest` and `src` are interpreted as arrays of `unsigned char` and that `c` is converted to same type in order to compare the characters. Do you have a reference saying that the behavior is the same as `memcpy` when EOF is passed?

Comment: @Bob__: I think you are right and wildplasser is mistaken.  The effect of passing `EOF`, on common systems where it equals `-1`, would be to copy until `0xff` is seen.  No implementation I checked handles `EOF` specially; they just cast the parameter to `unsigned char` and proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ancient C, there was no way to pass an argument as an `unsigned char`; all arguments were promoted to at least `int`. Changing the parameter type to `unsigned char` now would break compatibility. (That could possibly be worked around, but there is no demand for it.)